# Android camera and predefined picture

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I have been searching for a tutorial on this matter but I can't find any. Basically I want to create an option on my App which lets you take a picture. The complicated part is that  there should be a predefined picture (lets say its a dog) which will appear at your side on the photo. It's like if you add a picture of a dog in the photo you have just taken.

The dog should appear on the camera preview and the taken picture should contain it. I will gladly appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) have samples that modify camera preview, such as apply color filters while previewing. I think one can define and put an image, too. Not that this is very easy.
There are also other specific augmented reality frameworks but I don't know much about them.